# Problem with symmetry and integral of motion in Classical Mechanics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, noethers-theorem, integrals-of-motion

I am currently working through the problem 4.10 in Kotkin and Serbo's book "Collection of Problems in Classical Mechanics". The problem consists in showing that the quantity
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_{i}}\left(\dot{q}_{i}X - \Psi_{i}\right) - L X
\end{equation}
is an integral of motion if the action is invariant under the transformations
\begin{equation}
q'_{i} = q_{i} + \varepsilon\Psi_{i}\left(q, t\right), \quad t' = t + \varepsilon X\left(q, t\right), \quad \varepsilon \to 0.
\end{equation}

My approach to solve this was to consider the difference in the action when the transformation is applied which is zero by hypothesis
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{t'_{1}}^{t'_{2}} L\left(q', \frac{\mathrm{d} q'}{\mathrm{d} t'}, t'\right) \; \mathrm{d} t' - \int\limits_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}} L\left(q, \frac{\mathrm{d} q}{\mathrm{d} t}, t\right) \; \mathrm{d} t = 0,
\end{equation}
and then expand the first integral in series for $\varepsilon = 0$, which would give
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{t'_{1}}^{t'_{2}} L\left(q', \frac{\mathrm{d} q'}{\mathrm{d} t'}, t'\right) \; \mathrm{d} t' & = \int\limits_{t_{1} + \varepsilon X(t_{1})}^{{t_{2} + \varepsilon X(t_{2})}} L\left(q + \varepsilon \Psi, \dot{q} + \varepsilon \left(\dot{\Psi} - \dot{q}\dot{X}\right), t + \varepsilon X\right)\left(1 + \varepsilon \dot{X}\right) \; \mathrm{d}t \\
& = \int\limits_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}} L\left(q, \frac{\mathrm{d} q}{\mathrm{d} t}, t\right) \; \mathrm{d} t + \varepsilon\left[L X\right]_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}} + \varepsilon\int\limits_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}} \left[L \dot{X} + \frac{\partial L}{\partial q_{i}}\Psi_{i} + \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_{i}}\left(\dot{\Psi}_{i} - \dot{q}\dot{X}\right) + \frac{\partial L}{\partial t}X\right]\; \mathrm{d}t + \mathcal{O}\left(\varepsilon^{2}\right).
\end{align}
So, to first order in $\varepsilon$ I have, using the equations of motion
\begin{align}
0 & = \left[L X\right]_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}} + \int\limits_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(L X + \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_{i}}\left(\Psi_{i} - \dot{q}_{i}X\right)\right) \; \mathrm{d}t = \left[2 L X + \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_{i}}\left(\Psi_{i} - \dot{q}_{i}X\right)\right]_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}},
\end{align}
which has an additional factor of $L X$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hm. I think I have answered a similar question in the past but can't find it now...